# How to upload and resize Joomla article images?

Tags: joomla, image-resizing, autoresize

Hereafter my problem. I have to update a website based on Joomla CMS, for now all is fine but I wonder if there is a way to upload and auto resize images so that when I associate them to articles I already have intro and full article images.

I know this is feasible in wordpress and there is also a crop system where you can choose different size.

Is out there some similar solution for joomla via component or some extension?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
https://ionutlupu.me/j-extensions/4-free-extensions.html

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/remote-local-image-manager
```

those two are free component for joomla to resize and upload image.

Answer (score 0):

A good paid solution is http://mapkcode.com/mk-extensions/mk-dropzone

Directly from the administrator panel you can drag your images into the dropzone area uploading them and resizing at the same time in two different sizes: intro and full

Otherwise you can try with some free plugin that auto generate thumbs:
http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/photos-a-images/images/resize-image-on-the-fly-and-cache